# I get error "Fatal Signal 11" try again RUN and it works

Tags: android

> A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xe49bba74 (code=1), thread 860

I get error this message when click to RUN. 
If I wait for this error then I click to RUN again, its working.
However I didn't wait error message click to RUN, I get this error message
but I don't know why?

Is there anybody know why?

Comment: Are you using any library? If so, which one(s)? Also you'll probably need to verify the device tombstone for further information on the crash. Take a look at this http://bytesthink.com/blog/?p=133 to help diagnosing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Fixed!;

Old code block:

```
String Service_VideoRecordingLooper="VideoRecorderLooper"; //This defined in AndroidManifest.xml <Intent-filter name="VideoRecorderLooper"..> in <Service...> tag.
startService(new Intent(Service_VideoRecordingLooper));
```

Fixed code block:

```
startService(new Intent(this,VideoRecordingLooper.class));
```